# how to explain the behaviour of this FSM example?

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I am trying to understand the akka FSM pattern, and in the following example I dont understand why I do not get a print corresponding to the processing -> complete. My print clearly indicates that I am in complete. Can someone please enlighten me?

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, FSM}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.FSM.Event
import akka.actor.Props

object FSM2 extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  val test = system.actorOf(Props[Test], "t")
  test ! Set("hello")
}

sealed trait State
case object idle extends State
case object processing extends State
case object complete extends State

sealed trait Data
case class Content(processing:Int) extends Data

class Test extends FSM[State, Data]{

  when(idle) {
    case Event(test:Set[String], _) => {
      goto(processing) using Content(test.size-1)
    }
 }
  when(processing, stateTimeout = 1 second) {
     case Event(StateTimeout, Content(count)) => {
     println(count)
     count match {
        case 0 => goto(complete) using Content(0)
        case _ => stay using Content(count)
     }
    }
  }
  when (complete, stateTimeout = 1 second) {
    case Event(StateTimeout, _) => {
      println("in complete")
      goto(idle) using Content(0)
    }
 }

  onTransition({
    case idle -> processing => {
    println("idle -> processing")
  }
  case processing -> complete => {
      println("processing -> complete")
  }
  })

  startWith(idle, Content(0))
  initialize()
}
output:
idle -> processing
idle -> processing
0
idle -> processing
in complete
idle -> processing

I thought this would be the expected output:

idle -> processing
0
idle -> processing
processing -> complete
in complete
(go back to idle with no print)
```

some other code I wrote suggests that it does not perform a pattern matching but an assignment instead.

It works if I use capital lettering on State objects (Idle, Processing, Complete and Idle -> Processing etc.)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is, that `case idle -> processing` doesn't match on your case objects but on anything and binds those anythings to the names `idle` and `processing`. In order to match on those case object, you have to match on a stable identifier, which means either starting the case object with an uppercase letter (as you've already observed) or surrounding them with backticks in your match:

```
case `idle` -> `processing`
```

With that in mind, it should be clear that the string `"idle -> processing"` is printed for every state transition, not just the ones from idle to processing, and you could verify that by printing `println(s"$idle -> $processing")`.

```
output:
idle -> processing // triggered by initialize(), is actually idle -> idle
idle -> processing // the actual idle -> processing transition
0
idle -> processing // processing -> complete
in complete
idle -> processing // complete -> idle
```

Comment: You can also fix this by renaming your case object to upper-case: 'Processing', 'Idle', etc. This way compiler will try to match on them.